# Using Crontab to run a php script

Tags: php, cron

I've got a PHP script that simply e-mails me a test message. If I go into my webserver cPanel I can create a cronjob that runs the script every 10 minutes and it works perfectly.

I manually schedule the cron job in cPanel using the following settings:

```
10 * * * * php -q /home1/user1/public_html/mail.php
```

Again the above works fine, but when I try to create the cron job via PHP instead of cPanel it never runs. When I check the cPanel to see if the job was actually created by my php script it DOES show up. All the settings that show up in cPanel are correct, it just doesn't run the script.

This is the PHP code I'm using to create the cron job:

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'10 * * * * php -q /home1/user1/public_html/mail.php'.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
```

I imagine it could be a permission issue or something like that? Not really sure why the job works when I create it, but doesn't when PHP creates it.

Comment: I'd say that the user that PHP runs under isn't allowed to create cron tasks by your server administrator. This would be a huge security hole in a shared environment.

Comment: Could be the case, but the cron job PHP creates does show up in cPanel :/

Comment: Guess I should read the question more carefully next time before commenting.

Comment: I would not try to modify the crontab with php. Whats about calling a cron.php every 10 minutes and inside the cron.php you can do your own crons defined by an selfmade textfile or database based cron-manager

Comment: I'm not too familiar with what you have described. Do you have any examples?

Comment: I think he's suggesting just make a single cron task that then reads from a database or a text file. That way you can schedule the cron task through the cPanel. What you are doing now should work though I think. I can't think of any permissions issues that would prevent it.

Comment: yeah I could do a workaround but I'd like to figure out why this isn't working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out...I'm sure what was wrong with the php code I was using above but it seems that was somehow causing the execution failure.

I'm now using the code below and the job schedules and actually runs :)

```
exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n10 * * * * php -q /home1/user1/public_html/mail.php" | crontab -');
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP shell scripts, e.g. cli/cron jobs, STILL require a `<?php` tag. e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$output = blah blah blah
```

Remember that there's no such thing as a "php script". There's only files that have PHP code blocks within them. Without an opening `<?php` tag block SOMEWHERE in the file, the PHP execution engine will never kick in, even though the file will have been processed/parsed by PHP.

Without `<?php`, the file's contents will simply be treated as plaintext output.

Comment: yeah all of my PHP files have <?php and ?>

Comment: again the job does schedule and show up in cPanel it just doesn't run mail.php

Comment: @user1647347 You don't need a closing ?> tag unless you are going to output something that's not to be rendered as PHP btw.

Comment: @user1647347: the closing `?>` is not required if there's no non-code output to be performed after the code section completes.